# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

Reference block of code below:

```
//create comment route: post new comment to database
router.post("/campgrounds/:id/comments", isLoggedIn, function (req,res){
  //lookup campground using ID
  Campground.findById(req.params.id, function(err,campground){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
      res.redirect("/campgrounds");
    } else {
      Comment.create(req.body.comment, function(err, comment){
        if(err){
          console.log("Error Occured");
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          //add username and id to comment
          console.log("New Comment User Name will be " + req.user.username);
          comment.author.id = req.user._id;
          comment.author.username = req.user.username;
          //save comment
          comment.save();
          campground.comments.push(comment);
          campground.save();
          console.log(comment);
          res.redirect("/campgrounds/" + campground._id);
        }
      })
    }
  });

});
```

I realized that if I emptied the database, created a new campground, adding the first comment to that campground is always successful and is displayed in the ejs html template at the "res.redirect..." statement. However, subsequent comment addition generates the error/warning below:

---

> (node:1400) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): ValidationError: Campground validation failed: comments: Cast to [undefined] failed for value "[{"author":{"id":"5a800e7d0646ee0837c2787e","username":"success"},"_id":"5a84b148a953bc03b4f58180","text":"Nice camp in a wooden environment... Yayy! I will be visiting this place next week","__v":0}]" at path "comments

---

Despite the warning/error above the code still executes to the line;

```
res.redirect("/campgrounds/" + campground._id);
```

However the ejs html template at /campgrounds/" + campground._id which contains a routine to loop through the comments on a particular campgrounds and display all of them, only shows the first comment, even though there are multiple comments against the campground.

below is the ejs template:

```
<% include ../partials/header %>

<div class=container>
  <div class = "row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <p class="lead">YelpCamp</p>

        <div class = "list-group">
            <li class = "list-group-item active">Info 1</li>
            <li class = "list-group-item">Info 2</li>
            <li class = "list-group-item">Info 3</li>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="thumbnail border">
            <img class="img-responsive" src=" <%= campground.image %> " alt="">
            <div class="caption-full">
                <h4 class="float-right">$9.00/night</h4>
                <h4><a href="/"><%=campground.name%></a></h4>
                <p class="text-justify">
                  <%= campground.description %>
                </p> 

            </div>
        </div>
        <p></p>
        <div class="card bg-light">
            <div class ="card card-header">
              <div class = "text-right">
                  <a class="btn btn-success" href="/campgrounds/<%= campground._id %>/comments/new">Add new Comment</a>
              </div>
              <p></p>
            </div>
                <% campground.comments.forEach(function(comment){ %>
                <div class="row"> 
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                      <strong> <%= comment.author.username %> </strong> 
                      <span class="float-right">10 days ago</span>
                      <p> 
                        <%= comment.text %> 
                      </p>

                  </div>
                  <hr>
                </div>
               <% }); %>

        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>


<% include ../partials/footer %>
```

Comment: Your question starts with a "reference code", reference to what? Then you start to talk about emptying databases and campgroups, what's that? Then a warning appears... Please rewrite your question so that someone who has no idea what you're doing understands what you're asking.

Comment: I was referring to the block of code just below the text "Reference code below". The problem is solved; I just needed to update the mongoose version I had installed.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the mongoose version to 5.0.6 from 5.0.1 cleared the warning.